# average pooling C++ error

Tags: c++, opencv, pooling

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
#define ATD at<double>

Mat average_pooling2x2(Mat mat, int padding_mathed)
{
int width_remain = mat.cols % 2;
int high_remain = mat.rows % 2;

Mat mat_new;
if (width_remain == 0 && high_remain == 0)
    mat.copyTo(mat_new);
else
{
    if (padding_mathed == 1)//valid
    {
        Rect roi = Rect(0, 0, mat.cols - width_remain, mat.rows - high_remain);
        mat(roi).copyTo(mat_new);
    }
    else //same
    {
        mat.copyTo(mat_new);
        if (high_remain != 0)
        {
            Mat row_add = cv::Mat::zeros(high_remain, mat_new.cols,mat_new.type());
            mat_new.push_back(row_add);
        }
        if (width_remain != 0)
        {
            Mat col_add = cv::Mat::zeros(width_remain, mat_new.rows, mat_new.type());
            mat_new = mat_new.t();
            mat_new.push_back(col_add);
            mat_new = mat_new.t();
        }
    }
}

Mat res(mat_new.cols / 2, mat_new.rows / 2, mat_new.type(), Scalar::all(0));


if (mat_new.channels() ==3)
{  


    for (int i = 0; i < res.rows; i++)//this is where error happened
    {
        uchar *data_res = res.ptr<uchar>(i);
        uchar * data = mat_new.ptr<uchar>(2*i);
        uchar * data1 = mat_new.ptr<uchar>(2*i+1);
        for (int j = 0; j < res.cols*res.channels(); j = j + 3)
        {
            data_res[j] = (data[j*2] + data[j*2+3] + data1[j*2] + data1[j*2+3]) / 4;
            data_res[j + 1] = (data[j*2+1] + data[j*2+4] + data1[j*2+1] + data1[j*2+4]) / 4;
            data_res[j + 2] = (data[j*2+2] + data[j*2+5] + data1[j*2+2] + data1[j*2+5]) / 4;

        }
    }

}

else
{
    for (int i = 0; i<res.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<res.cols; j++)
        {
            Mat temp;
            Rect roi = Rect(j * 2, i * 2, 2, 2);
            mat_new(roi).copyTo(temp);
            double val;
            val = sum(temp)[0] / (2 * 2);
            res.ATD(i, j) = val;
        }
    }

}

return res;


}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat image = imread("C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//11.jpg");
    imshow("???", image);
    Mat pooling_image;
    average_pooling2x2(image, 2).copyTo(pooling_image);
    imshow("???", pooling_image);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0])) in cv::Mat::ptr, file d:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 827

reccently I try to implement the average pooling using C++, this is the error when I run the code, it seems that maybe the ptr pointer is out of range. but I just can not figure out where is the problem. Really need some help

Comment: The line that you marked as "this is where error happened" can not cause described error because it only contains integer operations. Most likely it happens somewhere below. For example at `mat_new.ptr<uchar>(2*i+1);`. For me it is not obvious whether `mat_new` has twice as many rows with some extra as `res`. Also you should name your variables properly, dummy names such as `data`, `data1`, `i`, `j` are just a straight road to fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you opened the file that the error message references to, you would see that the `ptr()` method is defined as follows:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp* Mat::ptr(int y)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) );
    return (_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*y);
}
```

Everything inside `CV_DbgAssert()` must evaluate to `true` - otherwise the program is going to crash at runtime. From that condition, it is clear that you are referring to the row in your program that is outside of Mat boundaries (the variable `y` above).

In your case, I can see several line where the program is going to crash.

In these lines, the crash happens when `i` gets equal or greater than `res.rows/2` (the first one will crash if res.rows is an odd number):

```
uchar * data = mat_new.ptr<uchar>(2*i);
uchar * data1 = mat_new.ptr<uchar>(2*i+1);
```

This loop will also crash, because `data_res` has only `res.cols` columns, and you allow j to reach `res.cols*res.channels()-1`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < res.cols*res.channels(); j = j + 3)
        {
            data_res[j] = (data[j*2] + data[j*2+3] + data1[j*2] + data1[j*2+3]) / 4;
            data_res[j + 1] = (data[j*2+1] + data[j*2+4] + data1[j*2+1] + data1[j*2+4]) / 4;
            data_res[j + 2] = (data[j*2+2] + data[j*2+5] + data1[j*2+2] + data1[j*2+5]) / 4;

        }
```

Also, I believe that here:

```
Mat res(mat_new.cols / 2, mat_new.rows / 2, mat_new.type(), Scalar::all(0));
```

you may have accidentaly swapped arguments - `res` has `mat_new.cols/2` rows, whereas I think you wanted it to be `mat_new.rows/2`.